# Set css style on element when hover occurs on a different element

Tags: css, svg

I have two images in the layout. They layout cannot be changed. When I hover over the svg image, I change the fill color. I want to also change the fill color of the svg if I hover over the first image. Is this possible? It is important that the hover event occurs on the first image and not on the root div.

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/3awtx16v/

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/11/94/f3/1194f3b0cb86afdf0d610e7b0b105826.png" />
  <div>
      <svg enable-background="new 0 0 128 128" height="128px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="128px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><path d="M64,128C28.71,128,0,99.29,0,64C0,28.71,28.71,0,64,0c35.29,0,64,28.71,64,64C128,99.29,99.29,128,64,128z M64,10   c-29.776,0-54,24.224-54,54c0,29.775,24.224,54,54,54c29.775,0,54-24.225,54-54C118,34.224,93.775,10,64,10z"/></g><g><path d="M46.001,40.51c0-3.523,2.489-4.954,5.534-3.179L91.718,60.77c3.044,1.775,3.044,4.68,0,6.457L51.534,90.668   C48.49,92.443,46,91.014,46,87.49L46.001,40.51L46.001,40.51z"/></g></svg>
  </div>
</div>

svg:hover {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case yes no problem. Use the **[Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**

```css
svg:hover {
  fill: #ff0000;
}

.outer img:hover + div svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/11/94/f3/1194f3b0cb86afdf0d610e7b0b105826.png" />
  <div>
      <svg enable-background="new 0 0 128 128" height="128px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="128px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><path d="M64,128C28.71,128,0,99.29,0,64C0,28.71,28.71,0,64,0c35.29,0,64,28.71,64,64C128,99.29,99.29,128,64,128z M64,10   c-29.776,0-54,24.224-54,54c0,29.775,24.224,54,54,54c29.775,0,54-24.225,54-54C118,34.224,93.775,10,64,10z"/></g><g><path d="M46.001,40.51c0-3.523,2.489-4.954,5.534-3.179L91.718,60.77c3.044,1.775,3.044,4.68,0,6.457L51.534,90.668   C48.49,92.443,46,91.014,46,87.49L46.001,40.51L46.001,40.51z"/></g></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution only works when your HTML is exactly like this though.

Comment: Wasn't sure about the "+". The docs state "Any element matching B that is the next sibling of an element matching A (that is: the next child of the same parent.)". Thanks a million for illustrating how the "+" works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
img:hover + div svg {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

where `+` what I call neighbor selector though this one only works when the both sit beside each other.

hope that helps